# What is the default root MySQL password after ansible installs it?

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

The line in my ansible script that installs MySQL looks like the following:

```
 - name: mysql is installed (from apt)
   action: apt pkg=mysql-server state=installed
```

This succeeds in installing MySQL server but it's not clear how I can proceed from here.
Running a `mysql_user` action afterwards doesn't work because I cannot even authenticate as `root`.

Answer (score 3):

The password will be blank. If it doesn't work, you can always reset it:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html